# Why isn't Postgres using the index?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, indexing

I have a table with an integer column called `account_id`. I have an index on that column.

But seems Postgres doesn't want to use my index:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT "invoices".* FROM "invoices" WHERE "invoices"."account_id" = 1;

 Seq Scan on invoices  (cost=0.00..6504.61 rows=117654 width=186) (actual time=0.021..33.943 rows=118027 loops=1)
   Filter: (account_id = 1)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 51462
 Total runtime: 39.917 ms
(4 rows)
```

Any idea why that would be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because of:

```
Seq Scan on invoices  (...) (actual ... rows=118027 <— this
   Filter: (account_id = 1)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 51462                    <— vs this
 Total runtime: 39.917 ms
```

You're selecting so many rows that it's cheaper to read the entire table.

Related earlier questions and answers from today for further reading:

- [Why doesn't Postgresql use index for IN query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181074/why-doesnt-postgresql-use-index-for-in-query/21181183#21181183)
- [Postgres using wrong index when querying a view of indexed expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152566/postgres-using-wrong-index-when-querying-a-view-of-indexed-expressions/21180420#21180420)

(See also Craig's longer answer on the second one for additional notes on indexes subtleties.)