# Postgres not using index inside "IN" clause for UUID

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing

I have a table `users` with an index on `id`.

I have another table `orders` which belongs to `users` and has a `user_id` field which also indexed

I have the following query :

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT user_id FROM orders
    WHERE user_id = '4CF93940-390D-4D70-BE62-61AFC73663BF'
);
```

Here Postgres uses the two indexes correctly (by checking the output of EXPLAIN).

However if I do this:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT user_id FROM orders
);
```

(Removed the where clause from the inner Select)

It doesn't use any index at all. It doesn't use the index on `orders.user_id` since I am selecting all of it, but why doesn't it use the index on `users.id`?

Here is the explain output for the two queries:

```
Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=4.36..22.54 rows=1 width=16)
   ->  Index Only Scan using user_id on users  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=16)
         Index Cond: (id = '4cf93940-390d-4d70-be62-61afc73663bf'::uuid)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on orders  (cost=4.21..14.35 rows=7 width=16)
         Recheck Cond: (user_id = '4cf93940-390d-4d70-be62-61afc73663bf'::uuid)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on order_user_id  (cost=0.00..4.21 rows=7 width=0)
               Index Cond: (user_id = '4cf93940-390d-4d70-be62-61afc73663bf'::uuid)



Hash Join  (cost=30.88..67.21 rows=885 width=16)
    Hash Cond: (users.id = orders.user_id)
    ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..27.70 rows=1770 width=16)
    ->  Hash  (cost=28.38..28.38 rows=200 width=16)
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=26.38..28.38 rows=200 width=16)
                Group Key: orders.user_id
                ->  Seq Scan on orders  (cost=0.00..23.10 rows=1310 width=16)
```

*UPDATE*:

So running this query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM users
WHERE id IN ('4CF93940-390D-4D70-BE62-61AFC73663BF', '4CF93940-390D-4D70-BE62-61AFC73663BF');
```

uses the index correctly. So basically why is

```
WHERE id IN ('4CF93940-390D-4D70-BE62-61AFC73663BF', '4CF93940-390D-4D70-BE62-61AFC73663BF')
```

different from

```
WHERE id IN (SELECT user_id FROM orders);
```

Seems like both are just an array of ids.

Comment: It doesn't use the index because the seq scan is more efficient when returning all rows (or a large fraction of them) from the table `orders`. In the second example Postgres expects 885 rows from the 1310 rows to be returned.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yeah I get why it isnt using the index for `orders`, but once it has a array (or set) or `user_id`s why doesn't it use the index on `users.id` to find all the users?

Comment: As I said: because using a seq scan is more efficient if a large fraction of the rows in the table needs to be retrieved. An index scan requires more random I/O _per row_ than a seq scan. Find a row by index requires searching the index for the leaf node (1-3 I/O operations) and then another I/O operation to retrieve the row for the table. If you repeat that many, many times it gets very slow. A seq scan on the other hand, retrieves several rows with a single I/O operation - much more efficient if you need more than just a few

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187865/why-isnt-postgres-using-the-index

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for your reply. Yeah I understand the seq scan is more efficient when fetching large portions of the table. However, 1) These are toy tables I created right now (to hide the complexity of my tables) and they have nothing in them so it shouldn't be different in the 2 cases (see my update). 2) I changed my id column from UUID to integer and now it uses indexes both times as expected. It seems like it is a problem with the index on UUID.

Answer (score 0):

Have many more entries in `users` relative to the number of entries returned by the sub-select and Postgres will probably start using the index.

Also, `id in (list)`  can be very different to `id in (sub-select)` when Postgres is able to treat the construct as join (which it does, as `EXPLAIN`ed)